# how to add debug code? (should go to Debug, shouldn't go to Release)

Tags: c#, .net

I need to log a lot of information in my software for debugging.
However I need this option only during development, I would prefer to exclude all this code in Release.

Of course I can surround the place I want to debug with "if":

```
if (isDebugMode()) {
  Logger.log(blahblah);
}
```

But because my software is pretty time-critical, I want to avoid a lot of unnesseray "if" tests.

I.e. I think I need analog of c "#define #ifdef #ifndef". Are there any technics in c# or .net to solve my task easily?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `[ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")]` in front of your `Logger.log` method so it will only get compiled in debug mode and completely removed in release mode.

This is how the `Debug` class methods are all marked.

The upside of this compared to using the `#if` approach is that code with the `Conditional` attribute doesn't even exist at runtime, and all references to it get removed, instead of staying there with an empty body (or however you'd compile it conditionally).

Comment: Oh, I like that better.  Didn't even know about that, thanks ;)

Comment: Yea, the C# people really hate the pre-processor, so they tried to do all the useful stuff in actual code. I personally have mixed feelings about this in general, but in this case it's better like this :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm in favor of a construct like you propose above as well.  I do most of my development in C or C++, but still, I've been using C# for four years now and there are still plenty of new things for me to learn.  Thanks again +1

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you instead use the `DEBUG` symbol?

```
#if DEBUG
  // debug only code here
#endif
```

[Here is an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) describing all of the preprocessor directives available to you in C#, and you are also able to define your own preprocessor variables in your project's properties menu.

Comment: but how can I automatically #define DEBUG in "Debug" mode (also it shouldn't be defined in "Release" mode). Or should I swtich(comment/uncoment) #define DEBUG every time?

Comment: It's done for you by the compiler. If you look in debug more under defined symbols, you'll find `DEBUG`.

Comment: @javapowered: As Blindy points out, this one is done for you.  As I said in my post, you can define additional constants under a given build configuration by opening your project's Properties -> Build menu.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, you can use a combination of the "preprocessor" directives:

```
#if DEBUG
    ThisWholeSectionIsTreatedAsACommentIfDEBUGIsNotDefined();      
#endif
```

and the conditional attribute:

```
Debug.Assert(x); // Call will be removed entirely in non-debug build because it has conditional attr
```

However, it is important to realize that one of them is a part of the *lexical* analysis of the program and the other is part of the *semantic* analysis. It is easy to get confused. My article on the difference might help:

http://ericlippert.com/2009/09/10/whats-the-difference-between-conditional-compilation-and-the-conditional-attribute/

Answer (score 2):

You can use this as a native alternative for debug only logging:

```
Debug.Write("blah blah");
```

which will only be logged if this is a debug build.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional attribute could help in this case.

Something like this:

> ```
> class DebugModeLogger
> {
>     [Conditional("DEBUG")]
>     public static void WriteLog(string message)
>     {
>         //Log it
>     }
> }
> ```

Extract from MSDN:
The attribute Conditional enables the definition of conditional methods. The Conditional attribute indicates a condition by testing a conditional compilation symbol. Calls to a conditional method are either included or omitted depending on whether this symbol is defined at the point of the call. If the symbol is defined, the call is included; otherwise, the call (including evaluation of the parameters of the call) is omitted.